# Issues with Adobe Air Apps Android Lollipop

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

I'm having an issue regarding AIR based apps,in Android Lollipop. I have been developing games, using Flash... And was doing local device testing,without posting to Google play. On lollipop,the games icon is replaced by the default air icon, has anyone else experienced this, or found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in similar trouble and I figured it our somehow. Actually problem is due to dpi of device. You need to make sure to define icon for all kind of devices.. You need follwing size of icons
192px (xxxhdpi)
144px (xxhdpi)
96px (xhdpi)
72px (hdpi)
48px (mdpi)
36px (ldpi)
Here are the things that you need to do..

1. Select icons 36, 48 and 96px from publish settings of your Air app (the default way to add icons in Air App)
2. For 144px icon, you need to modify the descriptor(.xml) file of your app (which is in same folder as .swf file), and add following code within  tag
   yourIconFileLocation/iconName.png
3. Now the last which is 192px icon.. You can't simply add it the in descriptor file through xml code.. (you will end up getting an error during compilation).. So you need to rename your 192x192 icon as "icon.png", copy it and paste it in following path and replace the original file which is already present there
   C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC 2014\AIR14.0\lib\android\lib\resources\captive_runtime\res\drawable-xxxhdpi

Go back to Adobe Flash and publish your app. Voillaa!!!